# dataweave coersion string to array error

Tags: arrays, dataweave

I am having issue in transforming message in dataweave, in mule 3.7.
input XML has structure as below:
[input XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbD7m.png)

dataweave code:
[DAtaweave code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BDte.png)

error as below:
Exception stack is:
1. Cannot coerce a :string to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue:31 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
    header_key : payload.data.header.Key,
                                     ^
Cannot coerce a :string to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler:162 (null)

---

Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException: Cannot coerce a :string to a :array
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue.evaluate(ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue.scala:13)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.CSVWriter.writeCSV(CSVWriter.scala:70)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.reader.csv.CSVWriter.writeValue(CSVWriter.scala:44)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.Value$class.write(Value.scala:31)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode.write(ObjectNode.scala:11)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.internalExecute(Engine.scala:89)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:54)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:169)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor$WeaveOutputHandler.write(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:159)
    at org.mule.transformer.simple.ObjectToByteArray.doTransform(ObjectToByteArray.java:63)
    at org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer.transform(AbstractTransformer.java:415)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:425)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:373)
    at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:714)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:177)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:97)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:83)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:38)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:185)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:1)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:126)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Anyone has any idea what issue with the code?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see is the `map` operator expects an array and `payload.data.PO` doesn't exist. I know you are not getting a NPE, but can you check if that is your error?

Comment: Thanks Chad for your inputs. Actually I have to add * to enforce the map target as an array.